# Calculating number of coins

Tags: javascript

Q:I need to pay somebody 49 'fake-currency'. I have coins of denomination 1,2,3,4 and 5 and I can pay the amount with a maximum total of 15 coins. Let there be **M** ways of paying. Find the last 3 digits of M.

---

So I wrote a solution in javascript:

```
function pay() {
var waysOfPaying= 0;
for (e = 0; e < 10; e++) {
    for (d = 0; d < 13; d++) {
        for (c = 0; c < 16; c++) {
            for (b = 0; b < 16; b++) {
                for (a = 0; a < 16; a++) {
                    if ((a + b + c + d + e <= 15) && (a + (2 * b) + (3 * c) + (4 * d) + (5 * e) == 49)) {
                        waysOfPaying++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return waysOfPaying % 1000 ;
}
```

The answer my code gives is 333 however the correct answer is 714. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You don't state the number of coins you have of each denomination. According to your code, that is 15 of 1, 15 of 2, 15 of 3, 12 of 4, and 9 of 5. Is that correct?

Comment: @jalynn2 15 is the total maximum number of coins that can be used.

Comment: I think this problem is more suited for CSExchange than this... It has nothing to do with Javascript nor anyother programming language ;)

Comment: How do you know the answer is actually 714?  Unless I'm missing something, your code looks okay to me (apart from the use of global vars and inconsistent indentation ;) )

Comment: @MarkRhodes The source of the problem tells me it is 714.

Comment: Could it be that either the question isn't stated right, or the source is wrong?

Comment: I'm with Mark. Seems fine. It's an easy logic. I even changed the algorithm to check if order counts in the calculations and 714 don't appear. Could you copypaste the source?

Comment: i've looked for 5 mins and logic looks fine with me.... so answer is wrong. If you do find the correct answer let me know, I'm curious

Comment: @bduran [source](https://brilliant.org/computer-science-problem/game-of-stones/?group=P9GVATNaUL5Y)

Comment: It's not the same problem that you have presented. In the source order seems to count.

Comment: @bduran How do I modify my code to include the order?

Comment: Cross-posted on CS.StackExchange: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19304/755.  Please don't cross-post.  That is against site rules.  Instead, you can click the "flag" button and flag it for moderator attention and ask them to migrate it to another site, if you posted it on the wrong site.

Comment: @geekazoid If the question was about the algorithm, it would be more suited for [cs.se]. However, as stated, the question is about JavaScript code. The JS code implements the wrong algorithm, but you need to understand JS to determine this, which makes it a coding problem, so [so] material and not [cs.se] material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your algorithm is oriented towards the value of each coin. The problem is that it lost the importance of order: It finds that 9 coins with a value of 5, plus 1 coin with a value of 4 adds up to 49. But it misses the fact that 8 coins with a value of 5, followed by 1 with a value of 4, followed by another 5 also adds up to 49.

The original problem is based on moving from space to space, building a trail of moves to square 50. Focus on where you are, instead of the jump value. Think of the decision to be made on each space:
 - Are you on space 50? if so, you found a valid trail, count it.
 - Are you past square 49, or have you taken 15 moves to get here? If yes, this trail is ended, and there is no point jumping any further.
 - If no, then you can make 5 possible moves: jump 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 spaces. After each one, evaluate your position again.

Hint: use a recursive function to simulate your actions on a space.

Answer (score 2):

This question was also posted in cs.stackexchange.
I add a copy of my answer from there:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19304/calculating-number-of-ways-of-paying-with-coins/19305?noredirect=1#comment38911_19305

I would solve it with dynamic programming. Anyway, your code looks fine to me. You go over all the options, and count the ones who satisfy the conditions.

I ran your script and I saw that the number of options is exactly 333. If this is really the answer, so why in the question you were asked to give tthe last three digits?

I think, that maybe you need to count the options and consider the inner order.

For example: 5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,4 will be count as an option, and 4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5 will be count as another option.

In this case the number of option will be much higher, and it make sense to ask for the last three digits.

You can change your code to this version of the question easily, by counting the number of permutation (notice that there are identical elements) for each tuple (a,b,c,d,e) that satisfies your conditions. It will be much more efficient than going over all the options.

Comment: I think the link in your answer is dead.. Just read the last bit of your answer - that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As people have previously pointed out, the question you wanted answered is not the same as was stated due to the fact that order is significant.  The solutions you gave was correct without permutations (333).  However, I don't think trying all the options is a good way to solve this problem..

If you're interested to see that could be implemented in JavaScript see below:

```
function pay (target, maxCoins, partial) {
    function sumArray (array) {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
           sum += array[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }

    if (typeof target === 'undefined')
        target = 49;
    if (typeof maxCoins === 'undefined')
        maxCoins = 15;
    if (!partial)
        partial = [];

    var sum = sumArray(partial);
    if (sum === target) {
        return 1;
    } else if (sum < target && partial.length < maxCoins) {
        var childSolutions = 0;
        for (var next = 1; next <= 5; next++) {
            var copy = partial.slice(0);
            copy.push(next);
            childSolutions += pay(target, copy);
        }
        return childSolutions % 1000; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Not sure how long this would actually take to run though (I gave up after a couple of hours!).  The trick to solving it efficiently is to do what you did, but for each of the solutions you find, figure out the number of ways the coins can be rearranged.  Luckily there is a [well-known formula for this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) (see the "Multiset bit").  Below, is how your code could be adapted to include permutations..

```
var factorials = [1 , 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600, 6227020800, 87178291200, 1307674368000];

function permutations (a, b, c, d, e) {
    var n = a + b + c + d + e;
    var base = 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var arg = arguments[i];
        if (arg > 0)
            base *= factorials[arg - 1];
    }

    return n < 1 ? 1 : factorials[n - 1] / base ;
}

function pay() {
    var a, b, c, d, e,
        waysOfPaying = 0;

    for (e = 0; e < 10; e++) {
        for (d = 0; d < 13; d++) {
            for (c = 0; c < 16; c++) {
                for (b = 0; b < 16; b++) {
                    for (a = 0; a < 16; a++) {
                        if ((a + b + c + d + e <= 15) && (a + (2 * b) + (3 * c) + (4 * d) + (5 * e) == 49)) {
                            waysOfPaying += permutations(a, b, c, d, e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return waysOfPaying % 1000 ;
}
```

Which if you run, gives you the value of 714, which you were expecting.